# Eclipse installation and NetBeans plugin update problems

Tags: proxy, java, eclipse, netbeans

I cannot install Eclipse on my Windows 7 x64 PC, because the installer says

> Network Problem - The catalog could not be loaded. Please ensure that
> you have network access and, if needed, have configured your network
> proxy.

And when I try to install NetBeans plugins, I get a message

> Networking problem in
> http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/82_patch2/php/org-netbeans-modules-php-code-analysis.nbm
>
> Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be
> unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your
> firewall is not blocking network traffic. Your cache may be out of
> date. Please click Check for Updates to refresh content.

I think it is the same problem.
I try the same things on another PC on the local network and everything works.

Comment: Check your proxy and internet settings

Comment: how can i check proxy settings

Comment: Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings -> Proxy server

Comment: "use a proxy server for your LAN" is unchecked

Comment: What about the other computer? Does your network need proxy?

Comment: no other computer is ok

Answer (score -1):

In proxy settings, select *manual* and with checked options, edit them with your proxy address and port. If needed, add your PC username and password. It worked for me.